# How to use an object in JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

> THIS QUESTION MIGHT NOT HAVE A CERTAIN ANSWER...

Which approach is better to use for using an object in JSX.

1- declare an object and use that in all usages:

```
            const object = GlobalState.getInstance().getObject()
            <Component1 prop1={object}></Component1>
            <Component2 prop2={object}></Component2>
            <Component3 prop3={object}></Component3>
```

2- pass complete reference to object we want each time we use that

```
                <Component1 prop1={GlobalState.getInstance().getObject()}></Component1>
                <Component2 prop2={GlobalState.getInstance().getObject()}></Component2>
                <Component3 prop3={GlobalState.getInstance().getObject()}></Component3>
```

which one is considered to be convention? do they have any performance difference?

Comment: In example 2 you are getting the object 3 separate times each render. Whether or not it's a performance hit depends on what the function exactly does, but you'd want to write drier code

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered to be a good practice to:

1. Keep your code [DRY](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself);
2. To store results of intermediate calculations in separate variables, so, you can document it & let other know what's that.

This way, *number one wins*. It's also better for performance. Flawless victory!